# How do you output the selected options from an Angular Mat-select field as text in Html?

Tags: angular-material, multi-select, angular7

** **UPDATED** **

So I am looking at displaying a list of items from a multi select as plain text on another tab as a summary. Standard inputs are fine but the multi selects are causing issues.

Previously I have used an object Array with ngFor. However this isnt working when checking the .value of the multi select it appears blank. Removing the .value outputs [object Object] (see image below)

[image: html view]

**general.component.html**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <span>Funding Programmes:*</span>
    <mat-select #FundingProgKey class="form-control" placeholder="Funding Programmes" formControlName="FundingProgKey" multiple [compareWith]="compare">
        <mat-option>-- None --</mat-option>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let programme of programmeList" [value]="programme">{{programme.Description}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</div>

<strong>Funding Programme(s):</strong>{{FundingProgKey}}<br />
<strong>Additional Funding Programme(s):</strong> {{FundingProgAddInfo.value}}<br />
```

**programme.dto.ts**

```
export class Programme {
    FundingProgKey: number;
    Name: string;
    Description: string;
}
```

Your help is greatly appreciated

--
Kind Regards

Lewis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution is don't use FormController if you want this functionality. We refactored our code to use ngModel instead from Angular7 the functionality to use ngModel with FormControl was removed.

ngModel is a lot less code and seems to be faster.

Hope this helps